# How to iterate through a general tree and modify the values of its nodes?

Tags: python, loops, tree, nodes

Suppose that I have a tree and I want to change the values of its node, add 1 to them, for example. My code doesn't work! The values of the nodes are numbers.

```
for subtree in tree.subtrees():
    subtree.label() += 1
```

Comment: Can you add how your "tree" is defined?

Comment: Also, you can't increment a value that isn't mapped to a variable, what you are currently doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a int to a string.

```
subtree.label() # this is a string
```

You could do something like this:

```
for subtree in tree.subtrees():
    value = int(subtree.label()) + 1
    subtree.set_label(str(value))
```